# Finding records only if there are more than 1 instances of

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with probably 700k records. The sturcture of the table looks like this...

```
ID     Type       ValueA
553    1          DCM
553    2          DCMM
586    1          ADM
587    1          HDD
587    2          HDS
```

Bascially I can have multiple values in ID such as 553 and 587 shown in the example. In `Type` each subsequent records gets Type incremented by one. So 553 started with Type = 1 then 2. Some records have up to a dozen types. I'm trying to find out if there's a way that I can query this table to only show me data for ID's where there is more than 1 Type

Desired Result:

```
ID     Type       ValueA
553    1          DCM
553    2          DCMM
587    1          HDD
587    2          HDS
```

I should get these records only because 553 has 2 instances, so does 587. 586 would not be included because it only had one record.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if `type` is sequential and starts with `1` as you suggest, you can use `exists()` like so:

```
select *
from t
where exists (
  select 1
  from t i
  where i.id = t.id 
    and i.type > 1
)
```

otherwise, you could join on a derived table that uses aggregation and `having()` to find `id` that have more than one row like so:

```
select t.*
from t
  inner join (
    select Id
    from t
    group by Id
    having count(*) > 1
  ) as dup
  on t.id = dup.id
```

---

rextester demo (for both): http://rextester.com/IZUIAL81840

returns (for both):

```
+-----+------+--------+
| Id  | Type | ValueA |
+-----+------+--------+
| 553 |    1 | dcm    |
| 553 |    2 | dcmm   |
| 587 |    1 | hdd    |
| 587 |    2 | hds    |
+-----+------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
SELECT ID, Type, ValueA
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID, Type, ValueA
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
ORDER BY ID, Type, ValueA
```

Comment: Did you try specifying the fields? I just did * out of convenience

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this works? See this demo -- http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/675430 - it returns nothing.

Comment: If you grouping like that, then  `COUNT(ID)` will 1 for every row (for OP's example data).

Comment: @BobSki Did you provide valid sample data? I'm not seeing how this query would return the desired result you provided.  Do you have duplicated ID, Type, ValueA combinations?

Answer (score 0):

try with this :)

```
with xa as(
select *, count(id) over(partition by ID order by ID ASC) rwn
from tableName)

select *
from xa where rwn>1
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using a subquery :

```
select * from t where id in (
 select distinct ID 
 from t
 group by id
 having count(*) > 1
)
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/LARQJ13273